# Django realtime: : How to solve the NameError:name 'root' is not defined

Tags: python, django, node.js, push-notification, django-1.8

My goal is to build a realtime notification app in Django(1.8.5). It seems that I needed to install Redis and ishout.js. So I installed them by following the instructions.

I was making Real time notification using this video tutorial,since I am new to this development stack, Django web server, Nodejs and redis following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Tibla5fSqM

After making the project in Django, I put 'root' in the settings.py file under TEMPLATE_DIRS,:

```
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = {

        root('templates'),


}
```

the whole source code can be viewed at :
https://github.com/arunsingh/real_time_notification

Now when I run the command from Ubuntu 14.04 terminal: python manage.py runserver, this results in error message depicted below:

```
(global)aruns realtimenotif $ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/aruns/realtimenotif/realtimenotif/settings.py", line 79, in <module>
    root('templates'),
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Also, when I run "django-admin --version" on terminal, it states > 1.6.1 while following this tutorial video, when I ran "pip install django" && "pip install django-realtime"  then i noticed django downloaded is 1.8.5 version.

According to me as these API were developed during 2013-14 using django 1.5.1, Which according to current django(1.8.5) is bit outdated which may be resulting in such errors, Kindly correct me on this,if this may be one of the reason for errors.

Kindly suggest fixers to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Got the solution, I fixed it, root was defined by mistake, It was not defined any where. Its up and server is running now.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, I fixed it, root was defined by mistake, It was not defined any where. Its up and server is running now.

Questions stands resolved !

Comment: Mark your own answer as accepted, please and thank you!

Comment: it says " You can accept your own answer in 2 days" !! Hence, i have to wait minimum for 48 hours to make it happen.